Vue: Pushing to object containing array is updating ALL arrays
I declare an items object like so:
const newItem = {itemId: '', price: '0.00', discount: 0, discountedPrice: 0, batches: [2]}
const items = ref([{...newItem, ...{id: 0}}])

And I want to be able to push a new member to the batches key:
const addItem = () => {
    items.value.push({...newItem, ...{id: items.value.length}})
}

const addBatch = (batches) => {
    console.log(batches)
    batches.push(0)
}

But when I call addBatch from the template, it is updating all of the batches on every item:
<tr v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="item.id" class="bg-slate-200">
  <td class="p-1 text-center align-top">
    <input :name="'itemId[' + index + ']'"
      type="text"
      placeholder="Item..."
      v-model="item.itemId"
      class="rounded border border-gray-500 text-gray-900 p-1 w-full text-xs min-w-[100px]"
    />
  </td>
  <td class="p-1 text-center align-top">
    <div class="grid grid-cols-2">
      <div>
        <input v-for="(batch, batchIndex) in item.batches"
          :key="batchIndex + 'batch'"
          :name="'quantity[' + index + '][]'"
          :value="batch"
          type="number"
          placeholder="Quantity..."
          min=".001"
          max="1000000000"
          step=".001"
          class="rounded border border-gray-500 text-gray-900 p-1 text-xs w-full"
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <button @click="addBatch(item.batches)" //////// HERE
          type="button"
          class="text-xs bg-green-600 flex p-1 items-center rounded text-white ml-1"
        ></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>

I've tried everything but I can't get my head around why all of the batches are being updated instead of just the one being passed to the function?

Array variables are references so each time you add the same array with a shallow copy. The best solution to avoid any deep copying would be just to have a function to return a new item each time, or just put the new item into addItem:
1.
const newItem = id => ({id, itemId: '', price: '0.00', discount: 0, discountedPrice: 0, batches: [2]});
const items = ref([{...newItem, ...{id: 0}}])

const addItem = () => {
    items.value.push(newItem(items.value.length))
}




const items = ref([{...newItem, ...{id: 0}}])

const addItem = () => {
    items.value.push({id: items.value.length, itemId: '', price: '0.00', discount: 0, discountedPrice: 0, batches: [2]})
}


Thanks, that's what I ended up doing, I have to make any changes in 2 separate places but it's quicker and easier than any messing about

It's a problem with { ...newItem } creating a shallow copy instead of a deep copy.  With a shallow copy, the nested array value still points to the same array object in memory. This is why changing the array for one item changes the array for all items. The solution then is to do a deep copy instead.
const addItem = () => {
  const itemDeepCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(newItem))
  items.value.push({ ...itemDeepCopy, id: items.value.length })
}

